# How to create a SQL query for the given scenario?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

There is a table named `user_transaction` which has following structure:

```
transaction_id    mediumint(6)   UNSIGNED (PK)
transaction_no    varchar(55)
transaction_cc_avenue_no    varchar(55)
transaction_card_category    varchar(100)
transaction_user_id      varchar(32)
transaction_user_name    varchar(255)
transaction_user_email_id    varchar(255)
transaction_deal_code    varchar(10)
transaction_dc_id    smallint(4)
transaction_amount    float(10,2)
transaction_discount    float(10,2)
transaction_total_amount    float(10,2)
transaction_data_assign    enum('0', '1')
transaction_status    enum('success', 'inprocess', 'fail', 'cancelled')     
transaction_date    bigint(12)
transaction_update_date    bigint(12)
transaction_update_user_id    varchar(32)
```

I'm using UNIX Timestamp values in fields `transaction_date` and `transaction_update_date` to store the dates.
Now my issue is I'm getting today's date in the format dd/mm/yyyy say(11/07/2013) from the form in PHP. 
After getting this date I want to find out the following counts for today(i.e. 11/07/2013) only:

```
total count of all the transactions carried out,
total count of all the transactions having transaction_status as 'success',  
total count of all the transactions having transaction_status as 'inprocess',
total count of all the transactions having transaction_status as 'fail',
total count of all the transactions having transaction_status as 'cancelled'
```

The same output is also required for two dates(range of two dates with both dates inclusive).
I'm a newbie in this UNIX Timestamp manipulations.
Can anyone help me in this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @X.L.Ant: Should I post my SQL query which I tried in a question body?

Comment: Yes please post the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) `carried out`,
        SUM(transaction_status = 'success') `success`,
        SUM(transaction_status = 'inprocess') `inprocess`,
        SUM(transaction_status = 'fail') `fail`,
        SUM(transaction_status = 'cancelled') `cancelled`
FROM    tableName
-- WHERE  add your conditions here
```

and since you want to get all records from today's date only, assuming from `transaction_date`
you can convert the unix date into date, eg

```
WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date) >= CURDATE() AND
       FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date) < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This works perfect for my requirement. Can you please provide me the WHERE condition if I'm putting two dates say(01/06/2013 and 30/06/2013)?

Comment: `WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date) BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30'`

Comment: :Thanks for your second answer as well. But my date format is diffrent than the format you mentioned in the answer. Then how should I make use of this query? Should I write a PHP logic to change the format of date and then use in query?

Answer (score 1):

to filter out the today's transactions you can use WHERE date(now())==date(transaction_date)
or just create 2 dates from one 11/07/2013 converted to pair

```
11/07/2013 00:00:00 - 11/07/2013 23:59:59
```